# WPF MVVM Key Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm new to WPF, and the code I've written doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to move a rectangular paddle to the left when the left arrow key is pressed, but I get no response when I press the Left arrow key. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the View:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Left" Command="{Binding MovePaddleLeftCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

and here is the code in the ViewModel:

```
private ICommand _movePaddleLeftCommand;
public ICommand MovePaddleLeftCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand(ExecuteCommand, CanExecute);
    }
}

private void ExecuteCommand()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Left");
    MovePaddleLeft();
}

private bool CanExecute()
{
    return true;
}
```

Below is a more complete picture of the code in case it's relevant.

**GameView.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Arkanoid_MkII.Views.GameView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Arkanoid_MkII.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Width="1500" Height="800">
    <Canvas Name="GameArea" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Paddle.PaddleX}" Canvas.Top="750" Width="{Binding Path=Paddle.Width}" Height="{Binding Path=Paddle.Height}" Fill="{Binding Path=Paddle.Colour}"/>
    </Canvas>
    <UserControl.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Left" Command="{Binding MovePaddleLeftCommand}"/>
    </UserControl.InputBindings>
</UserControl>
```

**GameView.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class GameView : UserControl
    {
        public GameView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="Arkanoid_MkII.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Arkanoid_MkII"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Arkanoid_MkII.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="Black" Padding="100">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5">
            <views:GameView x:Name="GameViewControl" Loaded="GameViewControl_Loaded" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GameViewControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Arkanoid_MkII.ViewModels.GameViewModel gameViewModelObject = new Arkanoid_MkII.ViewModels.GameViewModel();

            GameViewControl.DataContext = gameViewModelObject;
        }
    }
```

**GameViewModel.cs:**

```
private ICommand _movePaddleLeftCommand;
        public ICommand MovePaddleLeftCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand(ExecuteCommand, CanExecute);
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteCommand()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Left");
            MovePaddleLeft();
        }

        private bool CanExecute()
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: How are the paddel related properties defined and what does the `MovePaddleLeft` method do?

Comment: The paddle is defined as it's own class Paddle, and it has a property "PaddleX" which defines it's placement on the X-axis. The MovePaddleLeft method reduces the PaddleX value, but I don't think that's the problem, as the MessageBox doesn't even show up, and a breakpoint in the MovePaddleLeftCommand isn't hit when I press the Left key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserControl` must be focusable and focused for the command to be executed:

```
private void GameViewControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Arkanoid_MkII.ViewModels.GameViewModel gameViewModelObject = 
        new Arkanoid_MkII.ViewModels.GameViewModel();

    GameViewControl.DataContext = gameViewModelObject;

    GameViewControl.Focusable = true;
    Keyboard.Focus(GameViewControl);
}
```